# How to make the contents of a cell stick to the top of a window?

Tags: html, css

I would like the contents of `mapCell` to be stickied to the top of the viewing window as the user scrolls down (`resultsTable` is very tall).

However, this merely resulted in only the very bottom of `map` being visible at the top of the page while `download` remains absolute-positioned.

```css
#map {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#mapCell {
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 492.883px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%" class="bottomTable">
  <tr>
    <td id="resultsCell">
      <table class="resultsTable" id="resultsTable"></table>
      <td id="mapCell">
        <object id="map" class="mapClass">
            <!-- SVG image -->
         </object>
        <br>
        <button id="download">Download Map</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put position sticky on `#mapCell`?

```
#mapCell {
  display:block;
  min-width: 492.883px;
  background:cadetblue;
  height:100px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top:0px;
}
```

*https://codepen.io/shaniemoonlight/pen/yLxqKLv*

Comment: That just moves the element to the top-left corner of the webpage; it doesn't make it stick to the top of the screen as my webpage scrolls, then returns to its regular position at the top.

Comment: I didn't read the question properly. Have a look at the new answer.